# What is the meaning of = {0}; in C?

Tags: c, initialization, stack

I found the construct `= {0};` in this C-code sample, found on [tidy.sourceforge.net](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/libintro.html)
What is the rvalue of the statement and is it ANSI C?

```
#include <tidy.h>
#include <buffio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv )
{
   const char* input = "<title>Foo</title><p>Foo!";
   TidyBuffer output = {0};
   TidyBuffer errbuf = {0};
```

Comment: It's an "initializer list". See 6.7.8, para 13 and onwards in the C99 standard.

Comment: @Steve Jessop, so would it be legal or illegal in C90?

Comment: it's legal. Initialization is 3.5.7 in the C89 draft I have. I think the section numbering is the same in C90 but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This initializes all fields in a struct, in your case `TidyBuffer`, to zeroes. The rule in C is that you can omit members in an initialization clause, and the rest will be initialized to zero. In C++, this is legal as well:

```
TidyBuffer output = {};
```

Comment: `{}` is not legal initialization in C.  (It is legal C++.)  The grammar requires at least one initializer; see 6.7.8p1 in C99.

Comment: I didn't know that; I've edited the answer. I wouldn't know why anyone in their right mind would prefer C over C++ though. :-)

Comment: In C, `{0}` even works for "plain" variables: `int i = {0};` is perfectly legal.

Comment: @pmg , so would <code>float f = {0};</code> work reliable too ?

Comment: @Sebastian: yes, `{0}` works reliably for initialization of objects of any type whatsoever.